# jQuery Ajax is not triggered in IE 6, 7, 8

Tags: jquery

My jQuery ajax call is working fine in **Chrome** and **Firefox**, but when I test it in **IE 6, 7, 8** it is not working **(the ajax call is not triggered, no request send to server**). Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: myURL,
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/text', //I also tried to use json
                dataType: 'text', //I also tried to use json
                data: {car_id: car_id, customer_id: customer_id},
                success: function(data) {
                    //SOME Code here deal with 'data'
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    //SOME Code here
                }   
 });
```

I have tried both '**text**' and '**json**' data type, but the code is not working in IE, no request send to server... how to get rid of IE problem??

---------------------EDIT----------------------------

```
myURL='/cars/reserved_cars/'
```

I am developing Rails 3 application, so the trigger means access **myURL** which will call **CarsController**'s **reserved_cars()** function.

Comment: What is 'myURL'? Is it the same URL as the page the request is being made from?

Comment: Can you post your surrounding code?  Like your trigger for this, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, the code as quoted works (if I remove `contentType`, which you said you'd tried): http://jsbin.com/ireko3

Some thoughts:

1. <s>Is `myURL` on the same server? If not, it could be that you're running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), but using a server that supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), which is supported transparently by firefox and Chrome but not (at all) by IE6 or IE7.</s>
   => That's not it, your edited question shows that the URL is on the same server.
2. <s>Is the other end *really* expecting text or JSON? Normally it would be expecting multi-part form data, and you wouldn't specify `contentType` at all.</s>
   => That's not it, you've said below that you tried it without `contentType`.
3. <s>Are you **sure** that the code is being run at all? I suspect you're not even getting to the `$.ajax(...);` call. Look for IE reporting syntax errors. There aren't any in your quoted code, but if you have some above it... One thing that fits this profile (Chrome and Firefox work, IE6 and IE7 don't) perfectly is if you have a dangling comma somewhere in an object literal, details: [*A literal improvement*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/literal-improvement.html)</s>

   => **Sigh** And *that's* not it, you've said it doesn't work in IE8 either, and IE8 doesn't have that problem.

You've said below that the link above doesn't work for you in IE6. It *should* work, and it does for me, so that tells me there's something going on in your setup.

Comment: Hi, I tried both define and NOT define content type, the IE is not working, and I am sure the other end expect text or json. So, your 2nd thought is not suitable in my case. But I am checking your 1st thought now, thanks!

Comment: I tried your link (http://jsbin.com/ireko3), I got error in IE 6, which says "error, status = error, error = No Transport
" which means it is not going to the success function.

Comment: @Mellon: Then there's something strange going on in your setup, that link works fine for me in IE6 (and it *should* work).

Comment: Hi,T.J. Crowder, your link is working in IE 7 and 8, I just tested.

Comment: @Mellon: And in IE6. I tested it before posting.

Comment: @Mellon @T.J. Another confirmation that it works in IE6 here. @Mellon is there something odd going on in your IE setup? Proxy server, something weird like that? Definitely got JS enabled? :)

Answer (score 0):

all, I think I figured out the reason. Since I am developing on Ubuntu 10.04, on which I installed a raw IE 6, and I am testing my code on this raw IE 6, things are always funky and not working.

I just moved my code to run in a Windows OS machine, things are working fine. Anyhow, thank you all for your great ideas.:)

Answer (score 0):

Here I think the browser is using `cache` sort of thing that's why its not sending request to server... `disable cache in internet options` and try again... if disabling the cache works then that means you `need to pass **random** querystring in the ajax call to server` so that it would send request to server everytime because the `url gets different` and browser cache no longer states valid for that !

I Hope i am able to understand your problem as I have also faced such problem once.

**And also the same problem persists in www.amazon.com's shopping cart when IE cache is enabled.**